# ¿Como puedo escuchar otro puerto que tiene un servicio si estoy conectado desde SSH por el puerto 22?

Tags: java, servicio, ssh

me encuentro conectado al servidor por ssh al puerto 22, y requiero escuchar otro puerto donde se encuentra publicado un servicio de java, no se si me debo conectar de nuevo ya no por el puerto 22 o si desde allí debo ejecutar algún otro comando para acceder a escuchar dicho puerto

Comment: ¿que significa para ti **escuchar** un puerto?  Si te refieres a conectarte a un puerto puedes hacerlo por telnet desde dentro del servidor con `telnet localhost puerto`.

Comment: Si, bueno, creo que estoy usando la palabra incorrecta, quiero ver los logs que arroja un servicio que esta publicado en un puerto, entonces a de ser así como tu dices, muchas gracias

Comment: Si quieres ver los logs deberias encontrarlos en el servidor en forma de archivos en alguna parte (o bien en /var/log/ o bien en la carpeta desde donde se ejecute el servicio o donde este definido en su configuracion), es decir, no hace falta conectarte a el supongo, a menos que sean logs guardados en base de datos que debas consultar desde dentro de tu propio servicio de alguna forma